# Log Archiving Solution

Tags: logging

What is the best solution for log archiving ? I have two application server (tomcat6) and I need to keep application log files for 7 years. Shipping, zipping and writing them on Bluray or DVD is time consuming, some the process is already automated but still takes so long, what do you suggest ?

Comment: How large are the logs?  How much data is being added per log rotation?  The file size and rotation scheduled are key to finding a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest solution to me is to use `syslog` or one of its derivatives (rsyslog, syslog-ng) to send all logs to central servers. (Plural because you may want to have some kind of failover for security, or load-balancing if the log volume is very high)

Primary components you need are:

- Compress logs with the most efficient algorithm you can afford depending on the log volume and computing power on the central server(s). `gzip` with the default aggressivity setting should do the job.
- Use the most resilient storage solution you can affrod (RAID5 seems a minimum)

Log files are very repetitive, so a day worth of application logs should have a very high compression ratio, allowing you to store your 7 years in a decent amount of hard-drive.

Comment: We are doing something similar and the mzsql built-in myisam pack is enough as today drives are big enough and you can keep a lot of data online and available without big costs.

Comment: Indeed. You can store a hell of a lot of log lines in a terByte-big HDD. Even Enterprise-grade drives aren't that expensive, even considering a fully-redondant storage solution.

Comment: +1. I have been gzipping my logfiles for years. Gzip's default encryption provides a decent balance between CPU usage, the time required to compress the data and file size. 100GB of logs is typically compressed down to 10GB. Higher compression methods like bzip and `gzip --best` use more CPU without significant reduction in file size. Another option is to use a filesystem like ZFS or a storage appliance like FreeNAS and use deduplication and/or compression together; and then optionally back up to tape afterwards. These solutions will typically provide RAID for disk redundancy.

Comment: See http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/log.php

Comment: Too bad this benchmark doesn't specify compress time. Intresting whatsoever !